# Should I share my seed phrase to earn airdrop tokens?

Tags: blockchain, cryptography, wallet-security

Someone on Face Book said I could earn free crypto by appying for an airdrop. He told me to download Blockchain from app store to my phone. I did this and created my account with a password. I also created my 12-word phrase. I was then told to go to: https://www.blockchainairdroptechnology.com/
This site then asked me to type in my 12-word phrase to receive my free crypto. Is this a safe thing to do? Is this a potential scam?[image: BlockChainMessage]

Comment: In general, if you have to ask if something is a scam, it probably is :p

Answer (score 17):

No, it is **not safe**. Never share your 12 word phrase. It is a backup of your private key and allows people to spend your money. They only need your public key or Bitcoin address to give you money, not your private key.